# Inner select on json when key is either string or array?

Tags: json, jq

I'm working with AWS S3 policy, where I get this JSON back (white washed):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn1",
          "arn2",
          "arn3"
        ]
      },
      "Action": [
        "access1",
        "access2",
        "access3"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket1/*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn1",
          "arn2",
          "arn3"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "access4",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket1"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "KEY1"
      },
      "Action": [
        "access5",
        "access4"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket1"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "KEY1"
      },
      "Action": [
        "access2",
        "access3",
        "access1"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket1/directory/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to filter out those two (last) arrays which have 'AWS: KEY1', leaving only the first two (which have 'AWS: [arnX]'.

As in, this is what I want/need:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn1",
          "arn2",
          "arn3"
        ]
      },
      "Action": [
        "access1",
        "access2",
        "access3"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket1/*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn1",
          "arn2",
          "arn3"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "access4",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket1"
    }
  ]
}
```

But I can't figure out how to do this! The 'AWS' is *either* a string *or* an array in the same JSON! No idea how to deal with both at the same time..

I've tried converting it to an array using `flatten`, but can't seem to select() on it. OR, then return the whole JSON (without the part I don't want).

```
$ cat /tmp/y | jq '.Statement[].Principal.AWS | [.] | flatten'
[
  "arn1",
  "arn2",
  "arn3"
]
[
  "arn1",
  "arn2",
  "arn3"
]
[
  "KEY1"
]
[
  "KEY1"
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
.Statement|=map(select([.Principal.AWS]|flatten|all(.!="KEY1")))
```

The `[.Principal.AWS]|flatten` bit does what you want to ensure you have a list of strings and not a single string. `all(.!="KEY1")` tests to make sure "KEY1" is not in the list. `map(select(...))` keeps only the statements that match the test.